# WPF drag and drop not working with empty image

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to allow the user to drop an image from explorer onto an empty `Image`(`Source` property not set), and I want the `Image` to be empty by default, but the `Drop` event will not fire if the `Image` is empty and my cursor will just be a circle with a slash. I tried adding a default image to the `Image` and it worked just fine. Is there any way I can make this work or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try put a layout container, such as Grid, outside the Image control, set it to be transparent, and then handle the drop event in the container